# How to say in German "The end of part A"

Tags: phrase-request, writing

I have a homework assignment with 3 parts

- Part A
- Part B
- Part C

I finished part A

How do I say it ?

"Das Ende der Teil A" ?

Comment: Could you clarify _what exactly_ it is, which you want to say?

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you are looking for (a) a way of telling somebody you have finished part A or (b) a type of heading or marker in a document that says "this is the end of part A"

Comment: @tofro
I want the other guy to read it (that this is the end of this part).

Comment: In my opinion "The end of part A" is not idiomatic in English for a written info at the end of one segment of a text. "End of part A" would be a better fit. - If this is what you really want to ask, you should consider editing your question to better reflect your intent. Subtle changes may change the meaning, so a correct answer is only really possible for a carefully worded question.

Comment: "Das Ende der Teil A" is wrong anyway, you have to use "des" instead of "der" : "das Ende des Teils A", but that is not good German, "Teil A ist beendet" is better German. But the translation of "I finished part A" is "Ich habe Teil A fertiggestellt".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly you want to say.

> I finished part A

can be translated as

> Ich habe Teil A beendet.
>
> Ich habe Teil A abgeschlossen.

or, if you want to focus on the status of your assignment, say

> Ich bin fertig mit Teil A.
>
> Teil A ist fertig.

The answer of Fayrooz

> Das Ende von Teil A

is only a literal translation of

> The end of part A

Comment: kann man in dem Fall nicht auch "erledigt" verwenden?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Da gibt es so viele Möglichkeiten. "Ich habe Teil A fertig", "Ich habe Teil A erledigt", "Ich habe Teil A vollendet" ...

Comment: "Das Ende von Teil A" oder "Das Ende des Teils A"?

Comment: @Trilarion Beides ist m.E. richtig, aber "von" klingt natürlicher. Außer man sagt "Das Ende des ersten Teils" ;)

Comment: @Trilarion: "Das Ende des Teils A" (Genitiv) is the correct version. While "Das Ende von Teil A" (Dativ) is used often, it is imho grammatically wrong and I would think less of people who say/write it like that.

Comment: @problemofficer You may be right. However, when searching for both versions, "das Ende von ..." is usually used in combination with a name: "Das Ende von Windows 7", as you wouldn't/couldn't say "Das Ende des Windows 7". So if you treat "Teil A" as a name, it is less incorrect

Comment: @Sentry: Yes, I agree. In this context "Das Ende von Windows 7" sounds better.

Comment: Oder "Das Ende des Betriebssystems Windows 7"

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Sentry: To focus on Part A and indicate that other parts will follow:

> Teil A habe ich abgeschlossen.

or

> Mit Teil A bin ich fertig.

If your are looking for a remark in a document I just would say:

> Ende Teil A

maybe horizontally centered as

> ---   Ende Teil A   ---

Comment: I don't want to say "I'm done with part A". But thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody translates "Part" with "Teil". I think "Abschnitt" or "Kapitel" is a much better wording if this is non-fiction. "Teil" is usually a phyical object, coloquial or a very unspecificy concept. Otherwise I like most other suggestions. For fiction however "Teil" fits.

Comment: Teil does not have to be physical. "Einen Teil der Zeit". "Ein Teil der Software." "Ein Teil des Films". If the homework is writing 3 parts, I'd agree with you and use a more specific term like "Kapitel". If it is one part writing, one part memorizing vocabulary, and one part reading a chapter in a book, "Teil" is perfectly fine.

Comment: It is however unnecessary unspecific,IMHO.

Comment: Thank you. I already submitted my homework the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Not a native speaker, but it sounds like what you're trying to get at is

> "Hier endet Teil A."

Answer (score 1):

Das Ende von Teil A,
Das Ende von Teil B,
Das Ende von Teil C

Comment: Thanks :D But from you name I can't tell if you are a native German, so I can't make sure your answer is correct yet. I will pick it as best answer as soon as I get verification. Thanks though!

Comment: Could you provide some information as to what exactly you are answering with this? As it is, your answer does not provide a correct answer to what seems to be the asker's question.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek It *does* answer the question in the *title* (which is, unfortunately, different from the question in the *main text*).

Comment: @Uwe You are correct, but even that doesn't seem to be what OP really wants to know...

Answer (score 1):

As a native German speaker I would like to add something, although the question is already answered:

Be aware that the correct answer depends on whether you are saying "I have finished part A" or writing a remark like "End of Part A" in a document - just like it does in English.
In the first case you would say something like recommended in the accepted answer by Sentry.

However, if you just want to leave a remark in something you write, "Ende von Teil A" would be the right choice.

Comment: Welcome at German.Stackexchange! I added the name, because an "accepted" is not final, but could be changed later.